# Gradle hanging on :app:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDebug

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My Android app will occasionally (about every 4-5 attempts) build very quickly (~7 seconds), but more often it gets stuck on this task: app:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDebug. This happens on most builds, and the build hangs indefinitely. My usual response is to cancel the build and then start again, but it's getting pretty frustrating and I'd like it to just build quickly every time. There's really nothing that should be that time consuming (I only have 4 activities and 5 model classes), so I'm pretty stumped as to what's happening.

**Here's the top level Gradle file:**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**And here's the app Gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yokogawa.jahziel.qcctourguide"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation group: "com.twilio.sdk", name: "twilio", version: "7.21.5"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```